# Rails 4 Composite Keys Returning Invalid Column Name Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4, composite-key

I'm working on creating a questionnaire data model in a Ruby on Rails application which requires composite primary and foreign keys. For this task, I am using the [composite-primary-keys gem](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys) with SQLServer, a pairing I have used in the past. Unfortunately, I am encountering a problem when I use the composite for lookup, whether I specify .find([x,y,z]), or use the methods defined by a belongs_to relationship. **Interestingly enough,** though, it functions properly through the relationships defined by has_many. My model is as follows (and the error will be towards the bottom of this post):

```
class QuestionSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_keys = :question_set_id, :generation, :language_id
  has_many :question_set_questions,
      foreign_key: [:set_id, :set_generation],
      primary_key: [:question_set_id, :generation]
  has_many :questions, through: :question_set_questions
end

class QuestionSetQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question_set,
      -> { where :language_id => Language.current_language.id },
      foreign_key: [:set_id, :set_generation],
      primary_key: [:question_set_id, :generation]
  belongs_to :question,
      -> { where :language_id => Language.current_language.id },
      foreign_key: [:question_id, :question_generation],
      primary_key: [:question_id, :generation]
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_keys = :question_id, :generation, :language_id
  has_many :question_set_questions,
      foreign_key: [:question_id, :question_generation],
      primary_key: [:question_id, :generation]
  has_many :question_sets, through: :question_set_questions
end
```

In case the model warrants explanation, QuestionSet and Question each have a composite primary key, consisting of three integers: question_ or question_set_ id, generation, and language_id. They are bound by QuestionnaireSetQuestion, which contains the id and grouping numbers, and uses the currently selected language (via `Language.current_language.id`) to materialize the proper record.

### What Works?

If I say something like:

```
qs = QuestionSet.first
qs.questions
```

Then everything works perfectly, and I see the exact results I expect. I have tested this very thoroughly, lots of questions, lots of question sets, lots of languages, lots of groupings. calling .questions on a QuestionSet works perfectly. It works the other way around too, with...

```
q = Question.first
q.question_sets
```

...returning the correct results every time.

Additionally, calling .question_set_questions on a Question or Question set functions correctly.

### What Doesn't Work?

If I say...

```
qsq = QuestionSetQuestion.first
qsq.question
# or
qsq.question_set
```

...I get an error. I get the same error when I say:

```
Question.find([1,1,1])
# or
QuestionSet.find([1,1,1])
```

That error is as follows:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [questions].* FROM [questions] WHERE ([questions].[question_id] = @0 AND [questions].[generat
ion] = @1 AND [questions].[language_id] = @2)  ORDER BY [questions].[question_id,generation,language_id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY',
 N'@0 int, @1 int, @2 int', @0 = 1, @1 = 1, @2 = 1  [["question_id", 1], ["generation", 1], ["language_id", 1]]
TinyTds::Error: Invalid column name 'question_id,generation,language_id'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [questions].* FROM [questions] WHERE ([ques
tions].[question_id] = @0 AND [questions].[generation] = @1 AND [questions].[language_id] = @2)  ORDER BY [questions].[question_id,generation,langu
age_id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int, @1 int, @2 int', @0 = 1, @1 = 1, @2 = 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Invalid column name 'question_id,generation,language_id'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [questions]
.* FROM [questions] WHERE ([questions].[question_id] = @0 AND [questions].[generation] = @1 AND [questions].[language_id] = @2)  ORDER BY [question
s].[question_id,generation,language_id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int, @1 int, @2 int', @0 = 1, @1 = 1, @2 = 1
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlser
ver/database_statements.rb:336:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlser
ver/database_statements.rb:336:in `handle_to_names_and_values_dblib'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlser
ver/database_statements.rb:325:in `handle_to_names_and_values'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlser
ver/database_statements.rb:300:in `_raw_select'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlser
ver/database_statements.rb:295:in `block in raw_select'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:
in `block in log'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instr
ument'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:460:
in `log'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlser
ver/database_statements.rb:295:in `raw_select'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlser
ver/database_statements.rb:244:in `sp_executesql'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlser
ver/database_statements.rb:19:in `exec_query'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlser
ver/database_statements.rb:199:in `select'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statem
ents.rb:32:in `select_all'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:
70:in `select_all'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:638:in `exec_queries'
... 1 levels...
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in `to_a'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:487:in `find_take
'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:105:in `take'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/composite_primary_keys-8.1.0/lib/composite_primary_keys/relation/finder_methods.r
b:124:in `find_one'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/composite_primary_keys-8.1.0/lib/composite_primary_keys/relation/finder_methods.r
b:97:in `find_with_ids'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:71:in `find'
        from c:in `find'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/composite_primary_keys-8.1.0/lib/composite_primary_keys/core.rb:26:in `find'
        from (irb):1
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'irb(main):
```

I'm sorry that's such a mess.
I believe the correct emphasis would be on

```
TinyTds::Error: Invalid column name 'question_id,generation,language_id'
```

From what I can tell, it's trying to find an actual column with the name 'question_id,generation,language_id', and failing because obviously no such column exists. I suspect the reason the other commands are working is because they build a .where statement out of those three fields, whereas this is misusing .find. That said, I'm only speculating based on the behavior I'm observing.

If anyone has any thoughts on this, I'd be incredibly grateful, as this is proving to be a major timesink, and I have yet to find anything on it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a table that didn't have a primary key defined in the database. I've created an issue here - https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys/issues/316 - and also posted a fix that worked for me.